# elementary OS Freya multimedia keys and Spotify

Tags: release-freya, spotify, dconf

I was having issues with the 0.9 version of Spotify and switched to the 1.0 beta of Spotify. After that my multimedia keys on my keyboard don't work. I've reset the defaults of my org>gnome>settings-daemon>plugins>media keys and that didn't do anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Someone from the spotify forum suggested either of these scripts: _Meanwhile, for those wanting a way to access the DBus interface without Gnome, they can use either:_

    https://mediakeys-daemon.googlecode.com/files/mkd.py (in Python)
    https://github.com/vincentbernat/dbus-mediakeys (in C)

But neither of them seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Multimedia keys are working fine for me in the latest testing version (1.0.9). In this article you can find how to install it: http://sysads.co.uk/2015/06/spotify-client-1-0-7-beta-for-linux-released/

```
# Use testing Spotify reposity
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com testing non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list'

# Add appropriate keys to verify packages
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 94558F59

# Install Spotify from testing repository
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install spotify-client
```

Comment: Did Spotify remove tray icon support in this version?